# How can I get the equivalent UTC day based on fromHours, toHours and user timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

Currently, I am working on a scheduling feature that looks like this. Given those parameters, I'm getting the from, to, and day of the week to run a specific task.

[image]

I automatically convert the from and to hours from the user's timezone and store them in UTC in the DB.

Assume the example in the image above

I have:

1. fromHours: 00
2. toHours: 01
3. timezone: Taipei GMT+8
4. Day checked: Friday

In UTC, the equivalent params for this input are:

1. fromHours: 16
2. toHours: 17
3. day checked: Thu
4. UTC Timne

I can convert the fromHours and toHours just fine using moment() library to UTC.

I'm struggling with how I can get the equivalent day in UTC based on the user's choice of fromHours and toHours alone.

I have the following code for mapping the checkboxes

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Checkbox } from 'antd';

interface checkboxButtonsProps {
  initialValue?: null;
  form?: any;
}

const CheckboxButtons: React.FC<checkboxButtonsProps> = ({ initialValue, form }) => {

  const fromHours = form.getFieldValue(['options', 'from']);
  const toHours = form.getFieldValue(['options', 'to']);

  const weekdays: { label: string; value: string }[] = [
    { label: 'Monday', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Tuesday', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Wednesday', value: '3' },
    { label: 'Thursday', value: '4' },
    { label: 'Friday', value: '5' },
    { label: 'Saturday', value: '6' },
    { label: 'Sunday', value: '0' },
  ];

  return (
    <Form.Item
      name={['options', 'days']}
      initialValue={initialValue && weekdays.map((it) => it.value)}
      style={{ margin: 0 }}
    >
      <Checkbox.Group options={weekdays} />
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

export default CheckboxButtons;
```

I would like to change the value of each weekday label to have the corresponding UTC value based on the shift in fromHours and toHours of the user.

I believe there can only be 3 cases for this (but I'm not sure):

1. Subtract 1 day if GMT+X Timezone shift
2. Keep the day the same (if the shift is within the same day)
3. Add 1 day if GMT-X Timezone shift

I don't know how to implement this concept in a way that will work for all user combinations and all time zones.

I would like to keep the same structure for days [0 (Sun) => 6 (Sat)] but shift them based on the user input so for the example

Taipei timezone:
day: 5 (Fri)

UTC Timezone:
day: 4 (Thu)

I hope my concept is clear enough. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You will need to store the hours as *local* time, not as UTC! Otherwise you’ll be an hour off when DST or other shenanigans hit.

Comment: To be clear, you can calculate a *specific* occurrence in UTC, like *"next occurrence is at Thursday the 6th of April at 16:00 UTC"*. But you can't store "occurs every Thursday 16:00 UTC", because that's sometimes gonna be 00:00 Taipei and sometimes 01:00 Taipei, depending on DST (not sure about Taipei in particular, just a general example). — If you _do_ calculate a _specific_ occurrence, then converting that to UTC should be a simple matter of using the right API method.

Comment: @Yogi I know. We use it at work so it's for an existing project.

Comment: @Yogi My database value looks something like his

`1. Days: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "0"] [1]`
`2. From: "16" [2]`
`3. To: "17" [2]`





[1]:  (Static values in the code snippet above to be consumed by moment().day())



[2]: (UTC Hour equivalent of the user local hours)

Answer (score 0):

```
const convertLocalTimeToUTCTime = () => {
 const dateString = '2021-10-22T00:00:00';
 const [fullDate, time] = dateString.split('T');
 const [year, month, date] = fullDate.split('-');
 const [hour, minute, second] = time.split(':');
 const dateTime = new Date(year, month, date, hour, minute, second);
 return dateTime.toISOString();
};
//********  OR directly pass dateString to new Date *********//
const convertLocalTimeToUTCTime = (dateString) => {
  let date = new Date(dateString);
  
  return new Date(
    date.getUTCFullYear(),
    date.getUTCMonth(),
    date.getUTCDate(),
    date.getUTCHours(),
    date.getUTCMinutes(),
    date.getUTCSeconds(),
  ).toISOString();
};
```

Comment: But that's not really what I want. I can already convert with `moment().utc()` API method